# xregexp having different result

Tags: regex, typescript, xregexp

I want to validate string with rules:

- string must contain at least one letter
- string can contain only those symbols(but it's not a must): ' , - , ( , )
- if there is a symbol present in the string, it must also contain a letter(at least one *1st bullet*)
- only symbols are not allowed

so far I have come up with the following regex:

```
    static personName = XRegExp.cache("^[\\s\\p{L}\\'\\-\\(\\)]+(?=\\S*\\p{L})\\S+$");
```

which doesn't work correctly. Only `"^(?=\\S*\\p{L})\\S+$"` this helps with the letters, I struggle to understand how to add symbols to it so that all rules will be passed, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the chars you allow are restricted to those you enumerated you may use

```
var regex = XRegExp("^[\\s'()-]*\\p{L}[\\s\\p{L}'()-]*$");
```

If you want to allow any chars but only a subset of symbols, with "at least 1 letter" restriction use

```
var regex = XRegExp("^[\\p{N}\\s'()-]*\\p{L}[\\p{L}\\p{N}\\s'()-]*$");
```

See the JS demo:

```js
var regex = XRegExp("^[\\s'()-]*\\p{L}[\\s\\p{L}'()-]*$");
console.log( regex.test("Sóme (unknown-string) doesn't like it") );

var regex = XRegExp("^[\\p{N}\\s'()-]*\\p{L}[\\p{L}\\p{N}\\s'()-]*$"); 
console.log( regex.test("Sóme unknown-string (123)") );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/3.2.0/xregexp-all.min.js"></script>
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[\\s'()-]*` - 0 or more whitespaces, `'`, `(`, `)` or `-` chars
- `[\\p{N}\\s'()-]*` - 0 or more digits, whitespaces and the allowed symbols
- `\\p{L}` -  a letter
- `[\\s\\p{L}'()-]*`  - 0 or more whitespaces, letters, `'`, `(`, `)` or `-` chars
- `[\\p{L}\\p{N}\\s'()-]*` - 0 or more letters, digits, whitespaces and the allowed symbols
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score -1):

Try this regex

```
 ^[a-zA-Z0-9\'\-\(\)]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\'\-\(\)]*$
```

[Demonstration](https://regexr.com/4a9i0)

Comment: Why did you decide to disallow zeros?

Comment: I forgot to include 0s :)